# Basic Access Query Sum across fields

Tags: sql

I am still a bit of a beginner to Access. I am tracking inventory of medical supplies. I have the tables divided by month that they are inventoried. I would like to Query a Query to sum all of the categories for every month. I am starting with two months to see if I can get it right then build out from there. I am seeing the correct values but am not able to sum the total as the name is the same. Also there will likely be months where an item would appear only once and I would not want those to be excluded. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT MSCat.ItemNumber
     , Sum(FebQ.SumOfQuantity) AS SumOfSumOfQuantity
     , Sum(JanQ.SumOfQuantity) AS SumOfSumOfQuantity1
FROM (FebQ 
JOIN MSCat 
    ON FebQ.ItemNumber = MSCat.ItemNumber) 
JOIN JanQ 
    ON MSCat.ItemNumber = JanQ.ItemNumber
GROUP BY MSCat.ItemNumber;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your database-design is not ok. You should NOT create a new table for every month. All the data should be in the same table with a column "month". This will bring you more problems than you can imagine.

To give an answer (wich you should NOT use because of the wrong table design):

```
select mscat.itemnumber
,      ( select sum(sumofquantity) from janq where janq.itemnumber = mscat.itemnumber ) as jansum
,      ( select sum(sumofquantity) from febq where febq.itemnumber = mscat.itemnumber ) as febsum
from   mscat
;
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. It seems that you are right and I should go ahead and redesign the database and eliminate the month tables. Thank you again for the help.